# margin or borderWidth properties don't work correctly in react native

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

I have multiple blocks with the same style:

```
blocksContainer:{ // the container of all blocks
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
},
block:{
    width: SCREEN_WIDTH /4,
    height: SCREEN_HEIGHT /12,
    backgroundColor: "#2d2d2d",
    borderWidth: .5,
    borderColor: "#6faaa3"
},
```

and this is the result:

[image: my blocks]

as you can see, border gradually disappears and at some points doubles.
I also tried `margin` instead of `borderWidth`, but I got the same result!
does it have something to do with react native or my emulator?
note that it works correctly when I have less blocks:
[image: my app with less blocks]

Answer (score 0):

After getting an `apk` output from the application and running on a real device it works correctly and the reason it was behaving like this lies in Genymotion implementation.